# UFuncTypeError: ufunc 'matmul' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype('<U32'), dtype('<U32')) -> dtype('<U32') - Streamlit

Tags: python, machine-learning, linear-regression, streamlit

```
#Linear Regression Model 
@st.cache(allow_output_mutation=True)
def linearRegression(X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test):
    model = LinearRegression()
    model.fit(X_train,y_train)
    score = model.score(X_test, y_test)*100

    return score , model
```

---

```
#User input for the model
def user_input():
    bedrooms = st.slider("Bedrooms: ", 1,15)
    bathrooms = st.text_input("Bathrooms: ")
    sqft_living = st.text_input("Square Feet: ")
    sqft_lot = st.text_input("Lot Size: ")
    floors = st.text_input("Number Of Floors: ")
    waterfront = st.text_input("Waterfront? For Yes type '1',  For No type '0': ")
    view = st.slider("View (A higher score will mean a better view) : ", 0,4)
    condition = st.slider("House Condition (A higher score will mean a better condition): ", 1,5)
    yr_built = st.text_input("Year Built: ")
    yr_reno = st.text_input("A Renovated Property? For Yes type '1',  For No type '0': ")
    zipcode = st.text_input("Zipcode (5 digit): ")
    year_sold = st.text_input("Year Sold: ")
    month_sold = st.slider("Month Sold: ", 1,12)
   
    user_input_prediction = np.array([bedrooms,bathrooms,sqft_living, sqft_lot,floors,waterfront,view,condition,yr_built,yr_reno,zipcode,year_sold,month_sold]).reshape(1,-1)
    
    return(user_input_prediction)
```

---

```
#Main function


            if(st.checkbox("Start a Search")):
                user_input_prediction = user_input()
                st.write('error1')
                pred = model.predict(user_input_prediction)
                st.write('error2')
                if(st.button("Submit")):
                    st.text("success")
```

I am using Streamlit to build a ML model that take user input. In my main function it returns error `UFuncTypeError: ufunc 'matmul' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype('<U32'), dtype('<U32')) -> dtype('<U32')` and trace back to `pred = model.predict(user_input_prediction)` the main function will print out error1 but not error2

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck in same kind of situation where the model was throwing various kinds of errors.
But particularly for your case, let me tell what I tried :

This line of yours seems pretty well.

```
user_input_prediction = np.array([bedrooms,bathrooms,sqft_living, sqft_lot,floors,waterfront,view,condition,yr_built,yr_reno,zipcode,year_sold,month_sold]).reshape(1,-1)
```

Just try adding this line below your code

```
user_input_prediction = user_input_prediction.astype(np.float64)
```

Because here model was throwing error that your datatype is mismatch since inside all these values of features are in form of a matrix(numeric) so we need to convert it into floating values before doing any prediction.

Also try passing the user_input_prediction inside predict method as a list :

```
preds = model.predict([user_input_prediction])
```

This worked for me, hope it'll work for you as well